# Oracle - Order by column with NULL values in last position

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using `Order by` for records sorting. I want to select NULL records at last position in every sorting. 
Eg.

```
ASC - {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,NULL,NULL,NULL} 
DESC - {7,6,5,4,3,2,1,NULL,NULL,NULL}
```

How to do this in Oracle query?

Comment: order by <column> nulls last;

Comment: You'd think that this would be documented somewhere, huh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your order by clause should be as follows:

desc

```
order by <field_name> desc nulls last;
```

asc

```
order by <field_name> asc nulls last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic MySql Query and Yii2 based Code:

```js
Basic Query in MySql:

SELECT *, IF(cloumn_name IS NULL, 1, 0) as cloumn_name_alias FROM `table_name` WHERE 1 ORDER BY cloumn_name_alias, cloumn_name ASC;

For Yii2 Framework:

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => [
                    'position_alias' => SORT_ASC,
                    'position'       => SORT_ASC,
                ],
                'attributes' => [
                    'position_alias',
                    'position',
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

ASC  -

```
ORDER BY NVL(field, 10000000);  <-- a maximum big constant here
```

DESC  -

```
ORDER BY NVL(field, 0) DESC;
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but the `nulls last` syntax works without having to think of replacement values that are smaller or larger than all possible values.